# How to modify this code to enable tail call optimization in ES6?

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6, tail-call-optimization

I have written a function to sum values recursively, but it does not meet the criteria for tail call optimization in ES6 (for reasons I cannot articulate).

```
function sum(...values) {
  if(!values.length) { 
    return 0; 
  }
  return values.shift() + sum(...values);
}
```

How can I change it to be eligible for optimization?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Is Tail Call Optimization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization)

Comment: The general way to do that is to pass along an accumulator parameter of some sort. Personally I would just declare a local function that takes an extra parameter; I'd give an example but I'm not good at ES6 syntax yet :)

Comment: Ha ha I had typed in a function almost exactly like Bergi's answer but decided it was probably wrong.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed. It is topically similar to the linked question, but this is about JavaScript and is a fine example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do

```
return sum(…);
```

to make a proper [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). In your example, the `+` operation is still executed *after* the recursive call, which makes this not work.

The typical approach is to use a helper function with an accumulator parameter:

```
 function sum(...values) {
     function sumTo(acc, values) {
         if (!values.length) return acc;
         else return sumTo(acc+values.shift(), values); // tail-recursive call
     }
     return sumTo(0, values);
 }
```

When recursing over lists, you can also (ab)use the list itself:

```
function sum(...values) {
    switch (values.length) {
        case 0:  return 0;
        case 1:  return values[0];
        default: values.unshift(values.shift()+values.shift());
                 return sum(...values);
    }
}
// or alternatively:
function sum(acc, ...values) {
    switch (arguments.length) {
        case 0:  return 0;
        case 1:  return acc;
        default: values[0] += acc;
                 return sum(...values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Right - but is that really how you invoke a `. . .` function with an array parameter? I haven't worked with that ES6 stuff yet.

Comment: @Pointy: `sum !== sumTo`. `sum` is never called in this example.

Comment: @FelixKling yes, but ... oh I see. Ah, duhh, that makes sense.  It's an array already.

Comment: @Pointy: Should I use `...` for `sumTo` as well to make it clearer? I was not sure.

Comment: @Bergi no I think it's fine; I was just confused. I think (if you used `...`) you'd need to invoke it with `.apply()` and it'd be kind-of a mess, no?

Comment: @Pointy: I thought that as well, but actually `sumTo(acc, ...values)` would work. Regardless, I think it is much cleaner to use single arguments for lists if you have multiple parameters. After all, this question is about tail calls, not about spread parameters :-)